# How to handle NHibernate LINQ empty result set?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I want to retrieve list of roles for a logged in user.

Following is a code segment that reads user roles from the database.

```
ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
            var data = from s in session.Linq<ApplicationUserRole>()
                    where s.AppUser.ID = 1
                    select s.Role.Name;

             List<Role> list = data.ToList();
```

AppUser: User entity
Role: Role entity.
As there are no data in the database for user id 1, it doesn't return anything.

Return type data is NHibernate.Linq.Query and it is not null.

It throws following error when I attempt to convert it to ToList();

> "Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index"

How do I handle empty result sets?

Comment: +1: These types of annoyances make me lose faith in Linq-to-NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
List<Role> list = data.Any() ? data.ToList() : new List<Role>();
```

Comment: No, it just blows up on Any() with the exact same error message. From what I've seen, I think this is NHibernate Linq's way of telling you "I can't deal with your expression".